# Is there any way to use the table data as separate column in DB2 database

Tags: sql, database, db2

I want to use the table data as a separate column in DB2 database. For example, consider a table Employes contains EmpID, Address, DeptID, Hiredate. My question is, how to display particular hiredate as a separate column in a table?

Example

**29 March 2013**
Joined
not Joined
Joined
Joined

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Please give a more detailed example (original state, and what you want to retreive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples that you might want to look at.[DB2 examples](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_subselectexamples.htm)

Comment: Thanks Androidz for all your help:)

Comment: @Karthick Kathiresan No Problem, Hope it helps